# Highlight day in jQuery UI calendar widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, widget

I have a jQuery UI calendar widget that's displayed in my web application. I'd like to be able to highlight a specific day of the month when the user performs an action. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: do you want to create a event calendar?

Comment: Check this link https://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-simple-highlighting-of-specific-days-who-can-help-source-inside
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML :**

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
             if (date == myDate) {
              return [true, 'css-class', 'ToolTip'];

              }
           }
});
```

You need to write a CSS class for `css-class`. For more information [Click Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay)

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
//Set DatePicker to April 25,2014
$('#dateselector').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2014,4,25) );
```

Refer the following links for more details :

1. http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate
2. https://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-simple-highlighting-of-specific-days-who-can-help-source-inside

Hope it helps.