# append child element in jquery ui highlighted day

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I took a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075412/highlight-day-in-jquery-ui-calendar-widget) and its accepted answer, which makes something like this:

```
<td class="css-class" title="ToolTip" onclick="DP_jQuery_1375311040925.datepicker._selectDay('#datepicker',8,2013, this);return false;">
    <a class="ui-state-default ui-state-hover" href="#">9</a>
</td>
```

Is there any way to get from that to a code like this:

```
<td class="css-class" onclick="DP_jQuery_1375311040925.datepicker._selectDay('#datepicker',8,2013, this);return false;">
    <span class="hiddendesc">ToolTip</span>
    <a class="ui-state-default ui-state-hover" href="#">9</a>
</td>
```

I want at the time of the element creation (the day in calendar) to append a span child that contains the description, which will be displayed on hover using a tooltip.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could give every `<td>` the child span and a "blank" class (or something similar), which would never be displayed; then assign class "hiddendesc" to only the correct day. You only want the chosen day to have this tooltip, right?

Comment: Right! Actually if the day is in my list I need to put the description in a span that is hidden inside the 'td'. My tooltip plugin will read the span and show it but the span itself will not be visible.

Comment: What do you mean by your list?

Comment: I take the days from a DB and therefore I have a list of days to highlight